# sub-pages in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am trying to develop a university website,
Here the pland in the homepage:

```html
    
University of paris:
  -> Faculty of Science
-> Faculty of Economics
-> Faculty of letter
I want to have a common menu that repeats throughout the faculties example:
in my site there is a 3 Menu these three faculties, each faculty:
---> Dean word
---> History
---> ...
```

I want to save time and manage all the menus for all faculties in a single click, I want something that brings a can has a sub site, or sub-page
    Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token.

It allows you to insert tokens into the menu Path. So, if you have 3 sub-sites:

- yourwebsite.com/facultyA
- yourwebsite.com/facultyB
- yourwebsite.com/facultyC

you can configure your menu Path as:

- [faculty:name]/dean-word
- [faculty:name]/history

etc.

Now you have one sub-site menu, that shows different content depends on faculty.

Answer (score 0):

This module will help you do that : 
https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_editor

Comment: thank you for your answer, is what I can with this module automatically manage all the other faculties menu? and that it is going to publish in the desired site of the faculty? if you understood my idea is: the university has three faculties, 3 sub-sites, all three have the same menu but with different content,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split your menu in 2 menus? So you'll have common one...and other will depend on current page...or what ever is needed..

Comment: what i want to say is u want the same menu in all sub-pages but different content